# What exactly does " I go to school at 7" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, time

What exactly does " I go to school at 7" mean? Which one of these does it mean?

- leave home at 7
- take transportation vehicle at 7
- arrive at school at 7, or
- my first class starts at 7

Comment: It could also be said by a kindergarten child to specify at what age he or she will start in "the big school".

Comment: I will definitely take it as #1.

Answer (score 3):

That is a good list of alternate interpretations. It could mean ANY of those things, depending on the speaker and the context. Absent any other cues, I would assume #3 or #4 in your list of options.  But you should not assume that everyone (or even most) would understand it that way.

Comment: It **could** mean *any* of those interpretations and although @Richard understands it as #3 or #4, I would understand it as #1, because #3 and #4 would be phrased "I **start** school at 7"

Comment: I agree that this is ambiguous. I would guess #1 or #4 absent other context. It might be nice to expand this answer with a few alternative usages that reduce the ambiguity: I leave for school at 7; I arrive at school at 7; I attend school from 7-4p; etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually take it to mean

> the student leaves their house at 7am to travel to school

since 7am is very early for class to start in a normal situation. However, given other locations and situations it may be possible that *somethings* actually do start at 7am, e.g athletic practice.  Obviously, the speaker is depending on the listener's understanding and knowledge of common local practices.

Comment: Schools in China typically start at 7:30 - see http://www.brighthubeducation.com/social-studies-help/128666-why-school-starts-in-fall/

Comment: When behind in the race, one must run faster and longer to catch up and surpass...