# "I went to the amusement park at 11 am." - Does it mean "head out" or "arrive"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, verbs

**Example 1**

> I went to the amusement park at 11 am.

Which does this mean? Does it mean "head out" or "arrive"?

(1)

> I headed out at 11 am.

(2)

> I arrived at the amusement park at 11 am.

How about "come"?

**Example 2**

> "He came to my farm at 11 am."

**Example 3**

> "He came to my city at 11 am."

Comment: This has been asked before and quite recently. Please help me try to find the similar question.

Comment: Might be this, https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112677/what-exactly-does-i-go-to-school-at-7-mean  But I think I've seen a more recent one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "go to" mean "arrive" or "depart"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335410/does-go-to-mean-arrive-or-depart)

Comment: You asked this same question 3 months ago. How is this question significantly different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to know. "Went" is not as precise as "departed for" or "arrived at".

Even something like this is not precise:

"I went to school at 8 a.m."

It could mean 8 a.m. is when you left your house to get on a bus, or your class started, or you arrived at school for an 8:30 a.m. class.